# Bootstrap Selector Multiple Close Button

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select

I created a multiple select-option using bootstrap select plugin. I want to add close button like select-all or remove-all buttons.

It just closes when you click outside.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#multiple_selector').selectpicker();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<select id="multiple_selector" multiple data-actions-box="true">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
</select>
```

Here is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ozgunlu/dL6brmyp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `data-done-button="true"`

```
<select id="multiple_selector" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-done-button="true">
```

Comment: Nicely adds a 'close' button at the bottom: updated fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/6v3tuk8x/

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/) suggests adding `{ header:"header text" }` which will add a close button; with spaces as the header you get just the close button:

```
$(function() {
    $('#multiple_selector').selectpicker({header:" "});
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0s46g9k/

Answer (score 0):

You can `trigger` your select on action button using `class` like below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#multiple_selector').selectpicker();
  $('.actions-btn').on("click", function() {
    $('#multiple_selector').trigger('click');
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<select id="multiple_selector" multiple data-actions-box="true">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
</select>
```